# else without rescue is useless and expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, loops

This code gives me these errors in my ruby console:

1) warning: else without rescue is useless

2) syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Why am I getting both of these errors at the same time?

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'
require 'byebug'
require 'awesome_print'
require 'watir'

def input #takes user input and grabs the url for that particular search

puts "1) Enter the job title that you want to search for \n"
j_input = gets.chomp
job = j_input.split(/ /).join("+")
puts "================================= \n"

puts "1/2)Do you want to input city-and-state(1) or zipcode(2)? \n"
choice = gets.chomp

   if choice == "1"

    puts "2) Enter the city that you want to search for \n"
    city_input = gets.chomp
    city = city_input.split(/ /).join("+")
    puts "================================= \n"

    puts "3) Enter the state that you want to search for \n"
    state_input = gets.chomp
    state = "+" + state_input

    puts target_url = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes/?q=#{job}&l=#{city}%2C#{state}&cb=jt"


  elsif choice == "2"

    puts "Enter the zipcode that you want to search for \n"
    zipcode = gets.chomp

    puts target_url = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=#{job}&l=#{zipcode}&cb=jt"

  else
    puts "error"
 end


unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(target_url)
parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
resume_listing = parsed_page.css('div.sre-entry')
per_page = resume_listing.count
resumes = Array.new
counter = 0
result_count = parsed_page.css('div#result_count').text.split(' ')[0].to_f
page_count = (result_count.to_f / per_page.to_f ).ceil
current_count = 0
byebug

if counter <= 0
    unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(target_url)
    parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
    resume_listing = parsed_page.css('div.sre-entry')
    per_page = resume_listing.count
    pagination_resume_listing.each do |resume_listing|

    #resume_info = {

    #   title:
    #   link:
    #   skills:
    #   education:
    #}
    #resumes << resume_info

puts "Added #{resume_info[:title]}"

else

   while current_count <= page_count * per_page
    pagination_url = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=#{job}&l=#{zipcode}&co=US&cb=jt&start=#{current_count}"
    unparsed_pagination_page = HTTParty.get(pagination_url)
    pagination_parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_pagination_page)
    pagination_resume_listing = pagination_parsed_page.css('div.sre-entry')
    pagination_resume_listing.each do |resume_listing|

    #resume_info = {

    #   title:
    #   link:
    #   skills:
    #   education:
    #}
    #resumes << resume_info

    puts "Added #{resume_info[:title]}"
    current_count += 50
 end

end
end
end
end
```

It won't allow me to fix the else without rescue issue without telling me that it expects an extra end at the end of my code. Of course when I put the end there it does nothing and says that it wants another end

Comment: If you format (i.e. indent) your code, it should help ID your missing `end` statement.

Comment: Your method is way too long which makes it really hard to spot errors. From Robert C. Martin's **Clean Code** book: _"Functions should not be 100 lines long. Functions should hardly ever be 20 lines long."_

Comment: I have the code formatted on my end I was just having trouble getting it in the right format on here since it was one of my first times posting

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your code is horribly formatted, but it would first have to be formatted at all to be even that much. Once you format it, the answer is quite obvious, you have a mis-placed `end`.

```
puts "Added #{resume_info[:title]}"
 # Should be and end here for the "do" block above
else
```

Here is what it should be:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'
require 'byebug'
require 'awesome_print'
require 'watir'

def input #takes user input and grabs the url for that particular search

  puts "1) Enter the job title that you want to search for \n"
  j_input = gets.chomp
  job = j_input.split(/ /).join("+")
  puts "================================= \n"

  puts "1/2)Do you want to input city-and-state(1) or zipcode(2)? \n"
  choice = gets.chomp

  if choice == "1"

    puts "2) Enter the city that you want to search for \n"
    city_input = gets.chomp
    city = city_input.split(/ /).join("+")
    puts "================================= \n"

    puts "3) Enter the state that you want to search for \n"
    state_input = gets.chomp
    state = "+" + state_input

    puts target_url = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes/?q=#{job}&l=#{city}%2C#{state}&cb=jt"


  elsif choice == "2"

    puts "Enter the zipcode that you want to search for \n"
    zipcode = gets.chomp

    puts target_url = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=#{job}&l=#{zipcode}&cb=jt"

  else
    puts "error"
  end


  unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(target_url)
  parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
  resume_listing = parsed_page.css('div.sre-entry')
  per_page = resume_listing.count
  resumes = Array.new
  counter = 0
  result_count = parsed_page.css('div#result_count').text.split(' ')[0].to_f
  page_count = (result_count.to_f / per_page.to_f ).ceil
  current_count = 0
  byebug

  if counter <= 0
    unparsed_page = HTTParty.get(target_url)
    parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_page)
    resume_listing = parsed_page.css('div.sre-entry')
    per_page = resume_listing.count
    pagination_resume_listing.each do |resume_listing|

      #resume_info = {

      #   title:
      #   link:
      #   skills:
      #   education:
      #}
      #resumes << resume_info

      puts "Added #{resume_info[:title]}"

    end

  else

    while current_count <= page_count * per_page
      pagination_url = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=#{job}&l=#{zipcode}&co=US&cb=jt&start=#{current_count}"
      unparsed_pagination_page = HTTParty.get(pagination_url)
      pagination_parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(unparsed_pagination_page)
      pagination_resume_listing = pagination_parsed_page.css('div.sre-entry')
      pagination_resume_listing.each do |resume_listing|

        #resume_info = {

        #   title:
        #   link:
        #   skills:
        #   education:
        #}
        #resumes << resume_info

        puts "Added #{resume_info[:title]}"
        current_count += 50
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Lesson here is to **ALWAYS** format your code, for everyone's sake, most of all your own. There is no excuse to not be formatted, and not doing so leads to trivial problems like this that are difficult to find.

**NOTE**
I did not test this or run it, simply formatted, which made the mis-matched `end` obvious.